# Ngrx effect does not compile

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, store

I have created a NetworkStatus ngrx store/state and a service that checks if the app is online. I also need an ngrx effect that takes a fetchNetworkStatus action and uses the service to update the store with a boolean. However, i just can't seem to get it right and there are loads of errors, even before using the action. All the errors are connected to the effect, so i must have done a lot of things wrong there. I am struggling to understand all the effect methods.

Here are the errors i get in the terminal:
[image: Errors]

Here is my code for the effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class NetworkStatusEffects {
  constructor(
    private networkStatusService: NetworkStatusService,
    private actions$: Actions
  ) {}

  fetchNetworkStatus$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatus),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.networkStatusService.getNetworkStatus().pipe(
          map((networkStatus) =>
            NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatusSuccess({
              online: networkStatus,
            })
          ),
          catchError(() =>
            of(
              NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatusFail({
                errorMsg: 'Unable to fetch current incident',
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

And here is the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkStatusService {
  networkStatus = false;
  networkStatus$: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

  async getNetworkStatus() {
        this.networkStatus = navigator.onLine;
    this.networkStatus$ = merge(
      of(null),
      fromEvent(window, 'online'),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline')
    )
      .pipe(map(() => navigator.onLine))
      .subscribe(status => {
        this.networkStatus = status;
      });
      return this.networkStatus;
  }
}
```

as well as the actions:

```
export const fetchNetworkStatus = createAction('[NetworkStatus] Fetch networkStatus');
export const fetchNetworkStatusSuccess = createAction('[NetworkStatus] Fetch networkStatus status success', props<{online: boolean}>());
export const fetchNetworkStatusFail = createAction('[NetworkStatus] Fetch networkStatus status fail', props<{errorMsg: string}>());
```

and reducer:

```
export interface NetworkStatusState {
  online: boolean;
  error: string;
}

export const initialState: NetworkStatusState = {
  online: true,
  error: ''
};

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatusSuccess, (state, {online}) => ({
    ...state,
    online: online
  }))
);
```

What am i doing wrong here? The service just return a boolean, so it shouldn´t be too complicated to put in the store i think, i just don't understand how..

Answer (score 0):

you must have to return action from map

```
NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatusSuccess({
  online: networkStatus,
}).
```

and in catchError also

```
return of(
  NetworkStatusActions.fetchNetworkStatusFail({
     errorMsg: 'Unable to fetch current incident',
  })
)
```